# Activerecord-reputation-system Rails gem how to sort by votes and recency of vote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm using Activerecord-reputation-system gem for Rails.

1. I would like to call all products from the `Product` model sorted by their score(reputation).
2. Could you also tell me how I can limit the reputation by time period - let's say I want to sort all products by votes happened in the last month only.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually sort the collection, of course:

```
@products.sort! {|p1, p2| p1.reputation_for(:votes) <=> p2.reputation_for(:votes)}
```

Personally, I prefer a scope/join driven way to do this to allow the operand to stay an ActiveRecord::Association.

```
Products.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC'})
```

or using a scope:

```
def self.most_voted
  find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, {:order => 'votes DESC'})
end
```